# Pyspark - redistribute percentages

Tags: pyspark

I have a table like the following:

```
city | center | qty_out | qty_out %
----------------------------------------
 A   | 1      |  10     | .286
 A   | 2      |  2      | .057
 A   | 3      |  23     | .657
 B   | 1      |  40     | .8
 B   | 2      |  10     | .2
```

city-center is unique/the primary key.

If any center within a city has a qty_out % of less than 10% (.10), I want to ignore it and redistribute its % among the other centers of the city. So the result above would become

```
city | center | qty_out_%
----------------------------------------
 A   | 1      | .3145
 A   | 3      | .6855
 B   | 1      | .8
 B   | 2      | .2
```

How can I go about this? I was thinking a window function to partition but can't think of a window function to use with this

```
column_list = ["city","center"]
w = Window.partitionBy([col(x) for x in column_list]).orderBy('qty_out_%')
```

Comment: Could you explain the calculation of redistribute?  it doesn't seem like 10 / (10 + 23) = 0.303... for A.

Comment: @Emma - thanks for catching that. To clarify, for each city, I take the sum(qty_out_%) of the rows dropped, divide it by the # of remaining rows, and add that % to each row. So (.057/2) + .286 and (.057/2) + .657. It's ugly but I just ignore the qty_out, unless someone recomends a better way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not statistician, so I cannot comment on the equation, however, if I write the Spark SQL as literally as you mentioned, it'll be like this.

```py
w = Window.partitionBy('city')
redist_cond = F.when(F.col('qty_out %') < 0.1, F.col('qty_out %'))
df = (df.withColumn('redist', F.sum(redist_cond).over(w) / (F.count('*').over(w) - F.count(redist_cond).over(w)))
      .fillna(0, subset=['redist'])
      .filter(F.col('qty_out %') >= 0.1)
      .withColumn('qty_out %', redist_cond.otherwise(F.col('qty_out %') + F.col('redist')))
      .drop('redist'))
```